# How to detect whether switch() matches one of its cases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I have a code like this:

```
$("textarea").on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){     // Ctrl is pressed
        switch (e.which) {
            case 66: // "B" button on the keyboard
                alert("it is bold"); 
                break;

            case 73: // "I" button on the keyboard
                alert("it is italic"); 
                break;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The above code handles `Ctrl + B` and `Ctrl + I` on keydown of `textarea`. Also there is two lines of code which stop every things:

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

This ^ codes stops the action of any button. For example `Ctrl + S` is deactivate now ..! What I need is to define if that `switch()` function matches a case, then run those two lines, else don't run those two lines. How can I do that?

Comment: so add another `case` snippet for the codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `default` case!

```
switch (e.which) {
    case 66: // "B" button on the keyboard
        alert("it is bold"); 
        break;
    case 73: // "I" button on the keyboard
        alert("it is italic"); 
        break;

    default: // everything else
        return; // without preventing the default action
}
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Comment: That's interesting for me ... In first you understood my question wrong like Amit Ramoliya and A. Wolff ..! Ok well, thank you ... +1

Comment: It works as well .. But to be honest I cannot figure it out ..! What happens when `return;` executes? Why after that `return false` doesn't execute anymore?

Comment: @stack It returns, so any following code in handler isn't executed. But i would suggest you to remove `return false;` keeping only `e.preventDefault();`. This way, event still bubbles and if later you need to cacth for other logic keydown event at any ancestor level, it will still work. `return false;` in jquery is shorthand for `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @A.Wolff OH! That's really cleaver. thanks for explanation.

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok, reasonable reasons ...:-) I will remove it. tnx

Answer (score 3):

Try like this if key press other then `Ctrl+B` or `Ctrl+I` then it won't do anything.

```
 $("textarea").on('keydown', function(e){
                if(e.ctrlKey){     // Ctrl is pressed
                   var codes= [66,73];
                   var a = codes.indexOf(e.which);
                   if(a > 0){
                    return false;
                  }else{
                   // your stuff
                   }                     
                }
            });
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is redundant here :)

Comment: In your code `Ctrl + S` is still deactivate .. Actually I want something exactly the opposite of yours ..!

Comment: @stack Oh looks like we didn't understand expected behaviour then :(

Comment: @A.Wolff Unfortunately yes. I can write `return false` in the end of each `case`, But I wanted to know is there any better solution? *(because in reality there is 12 cases)*

Comment: `if(a > 0)` should be `if(a !== -1)`